# How can I add a day and at the same time specify a static time for that date?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Good I have a problem, I hope you can help me, the fact is that I have to get some time stamps from my database and add them one day, well, all right, I use the carbon addday (), but since carbon does not want to compare my timestamps then I have to convert to string where with a parse I can assimilate them to carbon, but in that process my date changes, the date is all normal but the time for some reason adds up to a few hours and that totally changes the result I am looking for, how could I solve it?
I pass my command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\p;
use App\Pe;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class LimpiarDiario extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'Task:LD';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Tasks';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       $datedi = p::select('p.Date', 'p.coddate')
               ->where('p.cod_paperiod', '=', 1)
               ->get();
           foreach ($datedi as $dateda)
            {
                $cod = $dateda->coddate;
           $now = Carbon::now();
            $dateli = $dateda->Date;
            $dateinter = strtotime($dateli);
           $datecar = Carbon::Parse($dateinter);
           $datetrans = $datecar->addDay();
           $datenue= $datetrans->toDateTimeString();
           if ($dateda->Date < $now)
            {
           $prueba= p::where('coddate','=', $cod)
           ->update(['Date' => $datenue]);

           }

           }
        }
```

to show the problem the result of my dateda is: `{"Date":"2020-06-12 16:00:00.000000","coddate":53}`
Then it becomes dateli and its value is: `2020-06-12 16:00:00.000000`
Again it becomes in dateinter and its value is: `1591992000`
and finally it becomes carbon with the variable datecar: `"2020-06-13T20:00:00.000000Z"`
and as you can see for some reason now it adds 4 hours to the original time so when I register the result it saves me the datenue: `2020-06-13 20:00:00`

When the desired result should be: `2020-06-12 16:00:00`

So as explained, I have to ask for help to know how I can set the time on the parse or how I could convert it the timestamps without changing the hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why all of this script just to make an update statement ...

```
$now=Carbon::now();

p::where('p.cod_paperiod', '=', 1)->where('date','<',$now)
    ->update(['Date' => DB::raw("Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY")]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The time generated by PHP is based on the time from the server config, but the time generated by javascript is based on your current device.